# Loop through array of arrays of string with spaces

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, shell, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through an array that contains other arrays and these arrays consist of strings with spaces. The problem is that I can't seem to preserve the spacing in the string. The string with spaces are either divided into multiple items if I change IFS to \n or all the elements of the array are seen as 1 item if I leave IFS unchanged here's some sample code:

```
#!/bin/sh
low1=("AA  QQ" "BB  LL")
low2=("CC" "DD")
low3=("EE" "FF")
high=(low1 low2 low3)

for high_item in ${high[@]}
do
   eval arrayz=\${$high_item[@]}
   #IFS=$'\n'
   for item in $arrayz
   do
      echo $item
   done
done
```

Output:

```
AA
QQ
BB
LL
CC
DD
EE
FF
```

As you can see the elements "AA QQ" and "BB LL" have been split.

If I uncomment the line that sets `IFS` to `\n` I get the following:

```
AA QQ BB LL
CC DD
EE FF
```

Now "AA QQ" and "BB LL" are concatenated!

Is there anyway I can preserve these elements just as they original are...I need the output to look like that:

```
AA QQ
BB LL
CC 
DD
EE 
FF
```

Comment: For `low1`, you have each element on a separate line. For `low2` and `low3`, all elements appear on a single line. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 5):

I think you meant that the output should look like:

```
AA  QQ
BB  LL
CC
DD
EE
FF
```

i.e.:

```
${low1[0]}
${low1[1]}
${low2[0]}
${low2[1]}
${low3[0]}
${low3[1]}
```

This could be accomplished using:

```
#!/bin/bash

low1=("AA  QQ" "BB  LL")
low2=("CC" "DD")
low3=("EE" "FF")
high=(low1 low2 low3)

for high_item in ${high[@]}
do
    x="${high_item}[@]" # -> "low1[@]"
    arrays=( "${!x}" )

    #IFS=$'\n'
    for item in "${arrays[@]}"
    do
        echo "$item"
    done
done
```

And **please** always use `#!/bin/bash` for bash scripts.

Explanation: `${!x}` is indirect variable expansion. It evaluates to the value of variable with a name contained in `$x`.

For our needs, `x` needs to have the `[@]` suffix for array expansion as well. Especially note that it is `x=${high_item}[@]` and **not** `x=${high_item[@]}`.

And you *have to* evaluate it in array context; otherwise, it wouldn't work as expected (if you do `arrays=${!x}`).

Ah, and as final note: `IFS` doesn't make any difference here. As long as you are working on quoted arrays, `IFS` doesn't come into play.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `eval` with indirect parameter expansion, and you'll get what I think you want (although it doesn't match your current given output:

```
for high_item in "${high[@]}"
do
    arrayz="$high_item[@]"
    # arrayz is just a string like "low1[@]"
    for item in "${!arrayz}"
    do
        echo $item
    done
done
```

Note the need to quote the array expansion in the inner loop to preserve the whitespace in elements of `low1`.