# Array elements with spaces are arguments to a function

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, arguments

```
myFunction()
{
    > /tmp/file_$1_$2
}

ELEMENTS=("first" "second" "a third" "a fourth")

for elem in "${ELEMENTS[@]}"
do
    myFunction "$elem"
done
```

I've tried the above code and a bunch of other variants found online:

[BASH array with spaces in elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084257/bash-array-with-spaces-in-elements)

[Loop through array of arrays of string with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300599/loop-through-array-of-arrays-of-string-with-spaces)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181507/bash-script-array-elements-containing-space-character

But I could never get this to work. What I want my code to do is iterate over these elements:

1. `first`
2. `second`
3. `a third`
4. `a fourth`

pass them to `myFunction` but have the function treat for example `a third` as 2 arguments, not 1! So I would end up with 4 files:

1. `/tmp/file_first_`
2. `/tmp/file_second_`
3. `/tmp/file_a_third`
4. `/tmp/file_a_fourth`

Whatever I try it either treats every word as a different element (6 calls to `myFunction`) or treats e.g. `a third` as one argument and creates a file `/tmp/file_a third_` or something different yet.

How do I do this right in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want word splitting to occur, then you shouldn't quote your variable:

```
myFunction $elem
```

Here's an example, using `printf` to demonstrate:

```
$ elements=("first" "second" "a third" "a fourth")
$ func() { printf '/tmp/file_%s_%s\n' "$1" "$2"; }
$ for elem in "${elements[@]}"; do func $elem; done
/tmp/file_first_
/tmp/file_second_
/tmp/file_a_third
/tmp/file_a_fourth
```

Comment: Finally, I had time to test it and it doesn't seem to work for me. Doesn't split the arguments, with or without the quotes.

Comment: @NPS I'm not sure why it isn't working for you - I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: I found out! I've been messing with `IFS` and that changes the behaviour. How can I set `IFS` to its default value?

Comment: @NPS the best thing to do is not to change it in the first place! But if you do, then you can always store the original value in a variable `old_IFS=IFS` and then restore it later `IFS=old_IFS`. Alternatively, you can run commands that use a different `IFS` in a subshell, or if it's just a single command, you can temporarily set the variable using `IFS=_ do_something`.

Answer (score 2):

Only remove double quotes when calling function:

```
myFunction $elem
```

The rest of code is ok.

However, you can try it using parameter expansion:

```
myFunction()
{
    > /tmp/file_${1// /_}
}

ELEMENTS=("first" "second" "a third" "a fourth")

for elem in "${ELEMENTS[@]}"
do
    myFunction "$elem"
done
```

I think this method can be better because if exists an element like this:

```
"a fifth ones"
```

myFunction() will create:

```
/tmp/file_a_fifth_ones
```

Explanation:

```
$ var1="I'm the content of a var"
$ echo "${var1// /_}"
```

Result:

```
I'm_the_content_of_a_var
```

Comment: The point about the possibility of more than two words is very good (and I agree), but this solution will not quite produce the same result as OP seems to want when there is only one word, since it won't insert a trailing _.

Comment: Your solution is good but I actually do more stuff in my function and I need arguments to be in separate variables. I could, of course, parse the input string and split it manually but that's not how it should be done.